# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 remove all instances

Tags: ssms, installation, sql-server-2017

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 for like 4-5 with some failures. I can't manage to have a clean re-install. I think there are some residual files or configurations.

I tired uninstall & reinstall, deleted all files download and redownload, cleaned regs (runned CCleaner).

How can I set everything so that I can perform a clean installation?

[image: Screenshot of actual instances.]

**UPDATE**

I found out that I can run that multiple times and remove them one by one. It's that enough?

**UPDATE**
Followed this tutorial https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/ as recommended by @Kin

Still can't get rid of these
[image: Can't uninstall these]

Comment: see if this still works for you in sql server 2017 - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4050/cleanly-uninstalling-stubborn-sql-server-components/

Comment: @Kin that worked somehow but didn't work for SQL Server 2017 Full text search & SQL Server 2017 Database Engine Services